# .Net FormStartPosition.CenterScreen not centering

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to center a form in VB.net. Instead of centering the form, it ends up about halfway between center and 0,0(upper left).

I am using the code

Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

Which is called from the IntializeDisplay Method, which in turn is called from the Form Load method.

I assume I'm setting some propertity along the way that messes up the center calculation, but I'm not sure what it could be.

If anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're setting the value of StartPosition too late in the flow - by the time Form.Load is called, Loading has already completed and the form has an assigned position.

Set a breakpoint on the line of code quoted in your question, and look at the forms position - it will already be in the location it appears.

To have the effect you want, the value of StartPosition needs to be set before the form starts its' built in location processing. I'd suggest putting the code in the form constructor, after the call to InitializeComponent().

Comment: That's only partly true. If the form is resized elsewhere or is set to auto-size, it really needs to be re-centered  in the load method.

Answer (score 4):

add this in the event and it will work:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're resizing the form, or are using auto-size you need to use a

```
    Me.CenterToScreen()
```

command at the end of the Load event.

Comment: That also works in a C# implementation during form load: `this.CenterToScreen();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the form initialization to handle its starting location, try calling the method to center the form.  This allows you to center the form even after you make changes to the size after it is shown.

Example:

```
Me.CenterToScreen()
```

Or

```
Me.CenterToParent()
```

Depending on where you are trying to center the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any form resizing/positioning logic implemented? If so, comment it out and try again.

Try setting the `Form.StartPosition` in the designer (which will set it in `InitializeComponent()`) instead of in the Load event.

Try resetting the `Form.Location` and `Form.Size` value. If your form is localized, remove the `Form.Location` AND `Form.Size` entry in the resource file.